# InelliJ IDEA merge command line tools usage

Tags: git, intellij-idea, command-line, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm trying to launch IntelliJ IDEA merge with the help of command line tools. In the instructions provided on: [Jetbrains merge command line tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/command-line-merge-tool.html) they specify 3 way merge with base, and suggest to leave it empty if you need 2 way merge (what I believe is my case).
So just to summarize I have branch ***foo1***,
file `foo.bar` with change in line 36 let's say -a +b,
branch ***foo2*** same file, with change in line 36 -a +c.
Now I try to rebase branch ***foo1*** onto ***foo2***, I run obviously into conflict. In git I see an issue to be resolved for my `foo.bar` file. How would you use mentioned merge tool from the command line, unfortunately I am not sure what params should be provided there... I've tried:
`idea merge foo.bar foo.bar foo.bar` (as I have same file and the result file should be the same as well, but the usage is somehow wrong and I end up with the dialog `Usage: idea merge []` after the IDE launches...

[image: merge usage result]

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You need to set full path to the files (e.g. idea merge /branch1/foo.bar /branch2/foo.bar /result/foo.bar).

Comment: can't make it work... the main idea behind not launching the intellij was its generation of additional folder/files, ended up using .git/info/exclude to ".gitignore" them and I launch merge from the ide directly.